# Code block structure highlighting extension for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Please,

Does anyone know an extension for Visual Studio Code that highlight code blocks ( for Javascript and HTML ) as in the image ?

Thank you

[image: Example]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Install the latest version of VS Code (1.3.0)
2. Edit your User or Workspace settings.json.
3. Add `"editor.renderIndentGuides": true`

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

```
"editor.guides.bracketPairs": true, // or active
```

Answer (score 1):

As of today, I would recommend `Bracket Pair Colorizer`, [git](https://github.com/CoenraadS/BracketPair), **if you use a bracketed language**.

Note: At the time of writing the note a new version 2 of the suggested extension were under [development](https://github.com/CoenraadS/Bracket-Pair-Colorizer-2).

Answer (score 0):

Use blockman, it does something like that