# how to navigate by paragraph or 'block travel' in VS code?

Tags: navigation, visual-studio-code

How do I navigate a paragraph or code block at a time in Visual Studio Code?

Called "block travel" in other editors...

I also can't seem to get matching bracket navigation to work.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Jumping_to_the_start_and_end_of_a_code_block
[Code block structure highlighting extension for Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296853/code-block-structure-highlighting-extension-for-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 9):

I found [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114166) on GitHub which discusses cursor navigation by paragraph/code block.  Here's what you need to do to enable this functionality:

1. Open the list of Keyboard Shortcuts in VSCode (Ctrl+K Ctrl+S on Windows).
2. Click the "Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)" icon in the top right corner of the pane (looks like a page with an arrow).
3. Copy the following lines in between the square brackets on the file that comes up:

   ```
   {
       "key": "ctrl+down",
       "command": "cursorMove",
       "when": "editorTextFocus", 
       "args": {
           "to": "nextBlankLine",
           "by": "wrappedLine"
       }
   },
   {
       "key": "ctrl+up",
       "command": "cursorMove",
       "when": "editorTextFocus", 
       "args": {
           "to": "prevBlankLine",
           "by": "wrappedLine"
       }
   }
   ```
4. Save the file.

You can assign these to whatever keybindings you want by changing what comes after `"key":`.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty handy and works for me.